# how to create a dynamic div on a React JS, and second is how to give that div a dynamic ID, this code below is JS code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to rewrite this code with React.js?

```
let tile = document.createElement("div");
      tile.id = r.toString() + "-" + c.toString();
```

Full code:

```
for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      let tile = document.createElement("div");
      tile.id = r.toString() + "-" + c.toString();

      let num = board[r][c];
      updateTile(tile, num);
      document.getElementById("board").append(tile);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use JSX. `<div id={...}></div>`. Also, simpler way would be `id={\`${r}-${c}\`}` or `id={[r,c].join("-")}`. However, its better not to use `id`. DOM manipulations are bad practice in React

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. Only ask one question per question

Comment: well you can create a `component` that takes `ID` as prop, then in a `for` loop create as many `components` as you wish.

Comment: instead of writing `r.toString() + "-" + c.toString()` use backticks to create a string: `${r}-${c}`

Comment: @tacoshy sorry, this is my first time asking question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this in your components render function, it would look something like this

```
return (
   <div id="board">
     {rows.map(row => {
        columns.map(column => (
          <div id={`${row}-${column}`} />
        ))
     })}
   </div>
)
```

Assume that div with id board is your board where you append created elements. Also I'm not sure what `updateTile` do, so if you would need some help with this, pls, share more details. And if you want just to render items, use code above

Comment: Thanks Oleg, for the response, actually im coding 2048game, I have the working code on JS, but I must code it with React JS, can I share here full code, so you can understand it?